# where is overloading operator in memory?

Tags: c++, memory, overloading, operator-keyword

I researched where the body of a function member is in memory and I know it is located in code segment and function member is only allocated once class is defined.

But where are bodies of overloaded operators located in C++?

Comment: Operator functions are *functions*, like any other functions, just with a special name.

Comment: I edited your question to make it more clear. If I misunderstood anything, please revert my edit and comment.

Comment: " ... with a special name" - and names usually don't make it into the executable anyway.

Comment: ok i understood :)

Answer (score 3):

Like any other function, it is in the code segment.

In the binary, an overloaded operator is the same as any other function or method.

The only difference between a normal function and an overloaded operator is the syntax to call them.